# Append utf8 content to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, utf-8, append

I read a utf8 character from URL and I want to append it in my page

> www.myurl.com/?machine=20&kaloupi=214Β

and the js :

```
var machine = getUrlVars()["machine"];
var kaloupi = getUrlVars()["kaloupi"];

function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
                        vars[key] = value;
                });
    return vars;
}

$('#title').append(machine+ '<small> (\ufeff'+ kaloupi+')</small>');
```

and I get 20 (214%CE%92) instead of 20 (214Β)

In my page I have `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: Your url is not correct: try with `www.myurl.com/?machine=20&kaloupi=214Β`

Comment: thx for noticing but it in not the problem..

Answer (score 0):

You output `\ufeff214B` which is character `0xfeff` (no-break-space) concatenated to `214B` which is just treated as a string as `\u` does not read beyond the preceding characters.

I assume you want `0x214b` (inverted ampersand), you can output the character:

```
String.fromCharCode(parseInt(kaloupi, 16));
```

Or the HTML entity:

```
"&#x" + kaloupi;
```

Comment: no, I want the Greek letter `Β`. Instead of this, I get `%CE%92`

Comment: I tried `\ufeff` before, as I thought it would solve the problem.

Comment: `\u214b` is `"⅋"` I thought that was your character code?  What character code do you want and how is it related to 214b?

Comment: the text is in Greek, and `214Β` is the code name for a product I use. It's just a name. So instead get `214Β` I get `214%CE%92`